# Most frequent letter with method errors

Tags: java, loops, counter

Trying to count array but having trouble treating it like any other type of variable
I get a missing method body error every time I try to compile along with a few other
errors, not sure what I'm missing.

```
  public static char maxLetterRecurrence(String sampleInput, int[]count);
  {

     int length=sampleInput.length();
     int letterCount = 1;
     int max = 0;
     char maxChar = 0;
     for(int i=1; i<length; i++)
     {  
         if(count[i]==count[i-1])
       {
         letterCount++;
       } 
       else 
       {
          if(letterCount>max)
          {  
           max=letterCount;
           maxChar=count[i-1];
          }
       }
       return maxChar;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
public static char maxLetterRecurrence(String sampleInput, int[]count);
```

to

```
public static char maxLetterRecurrence(String sampleInput, int[]count)
```

You should not have a semicolon on the end.

Comment: Thanks! Still having trouble comparing my  maxChar=count[i-1]; I cant figure out how I would store my max occurrence into a variable.

Comment: you are trying to convert an `int` to a `char`

Comment: although I am not understanding the logic that you are trying to use.